# Shapefile layers loading as the wrong geometry type

Tags: qgis

I have a QGIS project shared with a few users and one user, in particular, is having an issue that when she opens the project the layers (shapefiles) are loaded incorrectly - they've lost their styles and the geometry is incorrect - lines appear as points.  Other users have no problems when opening the project; layers and styles are displayed properly.  We can sort it out by using the "change data source" and re-map the layers, but obviously, we shouldn't need to do this.  Are there any known issues that would cause this?

Comment: It seems some of the data is incorrectly located. But without further information, details, screenshots etc. it is just guesswork - so additional context could help.

Comment: When you say shared, do you mean there is one project sitting on a shared drive which is opened and run by local installations of QGIS, or a local or network install of QGIS with different users logging in or a project that is copied and pasted to multiple computers but points to shared data, or something else?  If there are multiple installs involved I'd check the relative/absolute path settings and environment variables to start.

Comment: How are they getting the styles from the shape files? These aren't normally stored in shape files, are they?

Comment: Sorry, yes - it's a .qgz project stored on a local area network, multiple users open the project file with their own QGIS installation for different tasks.  Different users may edit the layer attribute data, but only one user saves the styles/project.  The shapefile layers are also all saved in the same network location and project settings use absolute path.  The current project we're working on works as expected for 3 out of 4 users, but the 4th user is having issues... This has happened once before on a different project, but for the same user.